# Illustrator curved line not so "pixel perfect"

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

As you can see in the image below, my curved lines inside the circle are not so "pixel perfect" like the outer circle, what can I do?

I did these curved lines using Path Finder: triangle + circle + 3 lines. Is there a better way to achieve this effect?

[image]

Comment: Your monitor has to use pixels to preview... how does it look if you save with "Art Optimized" anti-alias settings?

Comment: A little better, Screen (72ppi) + Art + Intercaled [Unchecked] right? Anything to get even better results?

Comment: Its only pixel perfect if the line is alligned pixel perfectly. Anyway this is why anybody sane would use multisampled lanczos filtering but no not Adobe.

Comment: Anyboby "sane" or experienced... I'm new to Illustrator, I'm not a professional designer. How can I use this "multisampled lanczos filtering"?

Comment: What do you mean with 'pixel perfect'? I don't see anything wrong with your image...